# Failure to parse string into a document

Tags: java, xml-parsing

Can anyone tell me how this code would result in a null document, but throw no exceptions?

```
document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><company>test</company>")));
```

Originally:

```
private Document load(String message) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    Document document = null;

    try {
        document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(message.substring(message.indexOf(XML_BEGIN),
                                                                                                                                        message.indexOf(XML_END)))));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
...
    Element element = document.getElementById(TIME_STAMP);
```

Results in:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ...view.MailReceiver.parse(MailReceiver.java:156)
at ...view.MailReceiver.notify(MailReceiver.java:99)
at ...view.MailReceiver.main(MailReceiver.java:72)
```

Comment: I'm afraid the original code snippet is pretty useless without the value of `message` (or at least what that `substring()` call returns) and the value of `TIME_STAMP`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the document being `null`.

```
// Parse XML into Document.
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><company>test</company>";
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory
    .newInstance()
    .newDocumentBuilder()
    .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

// Format Document to XML again. 
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(writer));

System.err.println(writer);
```

Prints out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><company>test</company>
```

so `document` wasn't null.

Printing out `document` gives you `[#document: null]`, which might be a bit confusing because it mentions `null`. This doesn't make `document` itself `null`, though.

Comment: However, I get an NullPointerException when trying to reference any of the methods on document; therefore, do I need to transform it first?

Comment: Could you add all of the code to your question and the full exception stacktrace? That might help in finding the problem :)

Comment: A few lines have been elided, but the essential behavior has been appended to the original posting.

Comment: The exception is thrown from this line: Element element = document.getElementById(TIME_STAMP);

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, I suspect the XML is badly formed due to the substrings being slightly "off".
When you're looking for your "XML_END" string then, assuming it's actually part of the XML you wish to parse (e.g. "" as a random example), you'll have to add on the length of this string also, or you'll missing part of your XML.
Also substring is exclusive on the endIndex so you might need a +1 in there too.

To start to check all this, I would assign the XML string (after substringing) into a variable and log it using log4j (or System.out.println) to see.

In your original code, if the parse exception occurs then you're dropping through to using the null document - not good! Possibly the cause of your NullPointerException. Usually you'd throw an exception in the catch block.